# Custom Timer Resolution vs System.Timers.Timer Resolution

Tags: .net, timer, f#, immutability

We have a need for a timer that fires on a given interval for a certain amount of time, then stops, and we want to asynchronously wait for the timer to stop.  Of course, this can be done with the `System.Timers.Timer` class, but it is a bit cumbersome and involves using an `AutoResetEvent` or similar.  In order to simplify this use case, I created a custom timer class.  Being an F# project, I made my timer immutable and based it on an agent, but I also wanted to be consistent with the way the .NET timers are implemented.  I took a look at the `System.Timers.Timer` reference source, and it seems to wrap `System.Threading.Timer`, which uses the Win32 `QueryUnbiasedInterruptTime` API.  I therefore used the same API when creating my timer to manage the timer interval.  However, I am observing different behavior between my timer and the `System.Timers.Timer` timer when testing.

When using my custom timer with a 1ms interval and a 100ms timeout, the timer will fire about 65 times with about 1.5ms between each event.  When using the `System.Timers.Timer` with a 1ms interval and stopping the timer after 100ms have elapsed (using a `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch` to check the elapsed time), the timer only fires 7 times with about 15ms between each event.  This seems more like the `System.Timers.Timer` is using `DateTime.Ticks` then `QueryUnbiasedInterruptTime`.  What problems may I be introducing with our custom timer being higher-resolution than the built-in `System.Timers.Timer`?  I was expecting consistent behavior, and was surprised to find them so different.

I am also concerned about a particular line I had to add to my function to compute the next interval.  I was seeing the `Elapsed` event fire twice for every elapsed interval instead of once, and the reason was that the time that had passed was less than one millisecond less than the interval, so it basically computed the next interval as zero milliseconds and fired immediately.  I corrected this by adding a check for the next interval being less than one millisecond and substituting the full interval, but this feels like a hack.  I have commented this line in the code.

The code for my custom timer is as follows:

```
open System

module private Timer =
    open System.Runtime.InteropServices
    open System.Runtime.Versioning

    [<DllImport("kernel32.dll")>]
    [<ResourceExposure(ResourceScope.None)>]
    extern bool QueryUnbiasedInterruptTime (int64& value)

    let inline private queryUnbiasedInterruptTime () =
        let mutable ticks = 0L
        if QueryUnbiasedInterruptTime &ticks
        then Some ticks
        else None

    /// Get the current timestamp in 100-ns increments 
    let getTicks () =
        match queryUnbiasedInterruptTime() with
        | Some ticks -> ticks
        | _ -> DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks

type private TimerMessage =
| Start
| Stop
| Wait of AsyncReplyChannel<unit>

type ImmutableTimer (interval: TimeSpan, ?timeout: TimeSpan) =
    let zero = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(0.0)
    let one = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1.0)
    let elapsed = Event<unit>()
    let intervalTicks = interval.Ticks
    let getNextInterval startTime = 
        match intervalTicks - (Timer.getTicks() - startTime) |> TimeSpan.FromTicks with
        // This feels like a hack, but is required to fix a near-zero next interval
        | x when x < one -> interval
        | x when x > zero -> x
        | _ -> zero
    let agent =
        MailboxProcessor<TimerMessage>.Start
        <| fun inbox ->
            let rec loop isStarted (waiter: AsyncReplyChannel<unit> option) endTime (nextInterval: TimeSpan) =
                async {
                    let startTime = Timer.getTicks()
                    try                        
                        let! message = inbox.Receive(nextInterval.TotalMilliseconds |> Math.Ceiling |> int)
                        match message with
                        | Start -> 
                            match timeout with
                            | Some time -> return! getNextInterval startTime |> loop true waiter (Timer.getTicks() + time.Ticks |> DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc |> Some)
                            | None -> return! getNextInterval startTime |> loop true waiter None
                        | Stop -> 
                            match waiter with
                            | Some channel -> channel.Reply()
                            | None -> ()
                        | Wait channel -> 
                            return! getNextInterval startTime |> loop isStarted (Some channel) endTime
                    with | _ ->
                        if isStarted
                        then Async.Start <| async { elapsed.Trigger() }
                             match endTime with
                             | Some time ->
                                if DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc(Timer.getTicks()) < time
                                then return! getNextInterval startTime |> loop isStarted waiter endTime
                                else match waiter with
                                     | Some channel -> channel.Reply()
                                     | None -> ()
                             | None -> return! getNextInterval startTime |> loop isStarted waiter endTime
                        else return! getNextInterval startTime |> loop isStarted waiter endTime
                }
            interval |> loop false None None

    let start () = agent.Post Start
    let stop () = agent.Post Stop
    let wait () = agent.PostAndReply Wait
    let asyncWait () = agent.PostAndAsyncReply Wait

    new (interval, ?timeout) = 
        match timeout with
        | Some t -> ImmutableTimer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds interval, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds t)
        | None -> ImmutableTimer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds interval)

    new (intervalTicks, ?timeoutTicks) = 
        match timeoutTicks with
        | Some t -> ImmutableTimer(TimeSpan.FromTicks intervalTicks, TimeSpan.FromTicks t)
        | None -> ImmutableTimer(TimeSpan.FromTicks intervalTicks)

    member __.Elapsed = elapsed.Publish
    member __.Start () = start()
    member __.Stop () = stop()
    member __.Wait () = wait()
    member __.AsyncWait () = asyncWait ()
    member __.StartAndWait () = start(); wait()
    member __.StartAndAsyncWait () = start(); asyncWait()
```

Example usage of the timer:

```
let mutable count = 0
let timer = ImmutableTimer(1.0, 100.0)
let stopwatch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch()
timer.Elapsed |> Observable.subscribe (fun _ -> printfn "%A: %d" stopwatch.Elapsed <| System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment(&count))
stopwatch.Start()
timer.StartAndWait()
stopwatch.Stop()
```

Comment: I would use Rx for this. Do I understand correctly that you want a timer to run a task every N milliseconds until X seconds have elapsed and then stop running tasks? You could use a combination of Observable.Timer and Observable.Timeout to achieve your aims in a single line I think.